# react will not allow me to push two elements

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass 2 elements within the todo array, however it just returns the term element value. I see no error in the console.

It seems that the

```
   items: [...this.state.items, this.state.term, this.state.name ]
```

only accepts two parameters.

I'm currently following this

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

```js
const { Component } = React;

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      term: '',
      name: '',
      items: []
    };
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({name: event.target.value, term: event.target.value});

  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      term: '',
      name: '',
      items: [
        ...this.state.items,
        this.state.term,
        this.state.name
      ]
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <form className="App" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange}/>
          <input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onChange}/>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.items)}</pre>

      </div>
    );
  }

}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve,

Comment: Agreed, although I notice `name` and `term` are always the same

Comment: seems like its a circular pattern in your items array.

Comment: What you want to do? I do not understand

Comment: @barnowl as far as what I understood, it works as you have expected. It is storing the two values 'name' & 'term' which are effectively same. Can you be more specific and check this out and let me know what's wrong. Check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/3n2zvl21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue you're asking about is the fact that your `onChange` event updates both `term` and `name` and whatever you type into one input goes into the other. Here's how you can resolve that:

- Add a `name` attribute to your `input` that corresponds to the key in the state.
- Access the value of `name` in `onChange` and update the value accordingly.

#### Solution

```js
const { Component } = React;

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      term: '',
      name: '',
      items: []
    };
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });

  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      term: '',
      name: '',
      items: [
        ...this.state.items,
        this.state.term,
        this.state.name
      ]
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <form className="App" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input name="term" value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange}/>
          <input name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onChange}/>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.items)}</pre>

      </div>
    );
  }

}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think your `this.setState` has any issue for your example.

You seem to be using `this.onChange` wrong.

I changed its implementation so that both input can have their own respective handler.

> onChange = key => event => {
>       this.setState({ [key]: event.target.value });   };

Also changed input callbacks to pass key value from the render function below.

```
  render() {
    const { term, name, items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="App" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input value={term} onChange={this.onChange('term')} />
          <input value={name} onChange={this.onChange('name')} />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>

        {items.join(", ")}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Your prior code was problematic which was rendering same value for name and term with whatever you type in any of your input boxes.